# How to push/pull only your changes to many mercurial branches?

Tags: mercurial

I have the following mercurial setup, with 3 or more repositories (all of the are remote)

- trunk
- branch_a - cloned from trunk
- branch_a_me - clones from branch_a
- local - cloned from branch_a_me

Inside `branch_a_me` I committed and pushed several change-sets but now I do have to assure that they are going to reach all the other branches.

I have to mention that even local is in sync with branch_a_me, there are changes that were made to all the other repositories and I do have to be sure that only my changesets are pushed/pulled to the others.

How can I achieve this with mercurial, preferably in a manner that would be easy to replicate the process later?

Comment: So, you made changes in `local` and pushed them to `branch_a_me`?  And now you want to push your changes from `branch_a_me` into `branch_a` and `trunk`?  Are other users pushing to `branch_a_me`?  `branch_a`? `trunk`?

Comment: *"I have to mention that even local is in sync with branch_a_me, there are changes that were made to all the other repositories and I do have to be sure that only my changesets are pushed/pulled to the others."* .. I do not understand this, could you explain this in other words?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such command in the repo.

The way it's supposed to be done, is that You merge Your code to places necessary.
So basically what You do is, select the branch to be merged, and the branch to merge Into.
Click merge, and resolve all the conflicts.

This can be automated by some batch script, and telling the repo to resolve all conflicts by taking Your code over the branch that changes are being merged into. NOT THE WAY TO GO.

The Way to go would be to merge Your changes to the MASTER branch, that all over's are inherited from. The moment people will try to merge their changes with the MASTER, they will get Your changes.

Comment: If you need to modify the build scripts, which are part of the SCM and you have products that are merging to trunk (master) maybe only two times a year...

Comment: To my understanding, You would still use the same approach. Put the build scripts into the master branch, and then pull the updates to all the branches needed. That's kinda the idea of the master branch (trunk) right ?